# Why does select(2) consider fd readable after newline instead of EOF?

Tags: c, sockets, select, io

I have this simple snippet from client:

```
...
//streamfd (usually stdin) is readable
        if (FD_ISSET(streamfd, &rset))
        {
            if ((bytesRead = read(streamfd, buf, BSIZE)) == 0)
            {
                //EOF of streamfd
                //negate the streamfd
                stdinfdOrEof = -1;
                Shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR);
                //remove the streamfd from the set
                FD_CLR(streamfd, &rset);
                continue;
            }
            Writen(sockfd, buf, bytesRead);
        }
```

Here the read() can read from `streamfd` (which is simply `fileno(STDIN_FILENO)`), because the `select()` mark that stdin as readable. But I typed just *one line* (following with `\n`), and the data was "ready to be read" (according to select()). What I would expect instead is, the file being ready to be read *after* `EOF`, not `\n`. What if I redirect a file with *many* newlines? then the select() will mark the file readable after every single line? No, it will do so after `EOF` (I have tried already), after which the client terminate (as in case of `EOF` the client calls `shutdown`, but in case of `\n`, the client can write more data). So why does `select` has multiple condition of when the file is considered "readable"? Or the "readability" condition is different for terminal device (stdin) and regular file (redirection) ? If so, what are they (conditions) then?

Comment: select says it is readable when it has data.  It knows nothing about newlines.

Comment: Well if I type some chars to terminal, it has data but select does not about them until I press `\n`. And since the select does the blocking (and not `read` waiting for input), the select is responsible for decision of when the data is ready, and they are ready **after** `\n` is pressed, so I suspect, select knows about new line

Comment: Unless you switch it to raw mode, a tty device is in canonical mode. It presents _line_ oriented data. It buffers up the data internally and only releases it [to `select`/`read`] after a newline. It is the tty layer/driver that does this, _not_ `select`. See `man termios`

Comment: Select says it's readable if read wouldn't block. Read returns data from a terminal when you type the newline. Therefore, select says it's readable. It's as simple as that.

Comment: As a side note, if you do `fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin)`, and you enter `hello world` but then _backspace_ over `world` and enter `galaxy` and then `newline`, you'll get `hello galaxy\n` in `buf`. It is the tty layer that does that line editing transparently to all other layers of processing

Comment: The _"What if I redirect a file with many newlines? then the select() will mark the file readable after every single line? No, it will do so after EOF (I have tried already)"_ makes me think you were actually using *pipes* as opposed to "redirecting from a file"...

Comment: When you redirect/read from a file, select will ALWAYS return true for the fd, since the file will always have data available (what data depends one where you are int the file) -- there's never any reason to block waiting for data.

Answer (score 2):

From https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html:

> A file descriptor is considered ready if it is possible to perform a corresponding I/O operation (e.g., read(2), or a sufficiently small write(2)) without blocking.

Calling `read` on a file descriptor that either has data available to read or that is at the end of the file will not block, so select considers it ready.